# Do not ignore case in sorting character strings

Tags: sorting, r, vector, character

Is there a builtin functionality in R to sort character vectors taking case into account? `sort` and `order` ignore the case:

```
tv <- c("a", "A", "ab", "B")
sort(tv)
## [1] "a"  "A"  "ab" "B"
```

This is my solution so far:

```
CAPS <- grep("^[A-Z]", tv)
c(sort(tv[CAPS]), sort(tv[-CAPS]))
## [1] "A"  "B"  "a"  "ab"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Following [post about Auto-completion in Notepad++](http://yihui.name/en/2010/08/auto-completion-in-notepad-for-r-script) you could change local settings:

```
Sys.setlocale(, "C")
sort(tv)
# [1] "A"  "B"  "a"  "ab"
```

---

EDIT. I read help pages to `Sys.setlocale` and it seems that changing `LC_COLLATE` is sufficient: `Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")`

To temporally change collate for sorting you could use [`withr`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=withr) package:

```
withr::with_collate("C", sort(tv))
```

You might think something could be done similarly with `stringr::str_sort` and its `locale` argument, but it doesn't work ([tidyverse/stringr#440](https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/issues/440)).

Comment: I had exactly the opposite problem, i.e. my default LC_COLLATE was "C" and I wanted to use case insensitive ordering. I didn't find anything better than trying some installed locales and the substitute the 3rd line of the function with Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "eu_ES.iso88591"). I'm sure it's wrong. What is the right way to do that?

Comment: A better method is to use `stringr::str_sort` and you can assign locale so it will have consistent result.

Comment: @FabioMarroni `stringr::str_sort` ignores current settings so it will sort case insensitively (`stringr::str_sort(tv)`).