# What are the R sorting rules of character vectors?

Tags: r, sorting

R sorts character vectors in a sequence which I describe as alphabetic, not ASCII.

For example:

```
sort(c("dog", "Cat", "Dog", "cat"))
[1] "cat" "Cat" "dog" "Dog"
```

Three questions:

1. What is the technically correct terminology to describe this sort order?
2. I can not find any reference to this in the manuals on CRAN. Where can I find a description of the sorting rules in R?
3. is this any different from this sort of behaviour in other languages like C, Java, Perl or PHP?

Comment: Related to [Do not ignore case in sorting character strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4245196/271616).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Details:` for `sort()` states:

> ```
>  The sort order for character vectors will depend on the collating
>  sequence of the locale in use: see ‘Comparison’.  The sort order
>  for factors is the order of their levels (which is particularly
>  appropriate for ordered factors).
> ```

and `help(Comparison)` then shows:

> ```
>  Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographicwithin
>  the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use:see
>  ‘locales’.  The collating sequence of locales such as ‘en_US’ is
>  normally different from ‘C’ (which should use ASCII) and can be
>  surprising.  Beware of making _any_ assumptions about the 
>  collation order: e.g. in Estonian ‘Z’ comes between ‘S’ and ‘T’,
>  and collation is not necessarily character-by-character - in
>  Danish ‘aa’ sorts as a single letter, after ‘z’.  In Welsh ‘ng’
>  may or may not be a single sorting unit: if it is it follows ‘g’.
>  Some platforms may not respect the locale and always sort in
>  numerical order of the bytes in an 8-bit locale, or in Unicode
>  point order for a UTF-8 locale (and may not sort in the same order
>  for the same language in different character sets).  Collation of
>  non-letters (spaces, punctuation signs, hyphens, fractions and so
>  on) is even more problematic.
> ```

so it depends on your locale setting.

Comment: D'oh. I was trying to find this in http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html.  Thank you.

Comment: I won't attempt to improve upon Dirk & the help's description, but outside of R, one might find it described as lexicographic sorting, albeit case-invariant.  The collation rule is a serious consideration, as naive text processing is usually done with regard to English order, which is bad for some other languages.  A good example is it makes name sorting look really weird to either native speakers *or* people who think only of 26 letters in strict A-Z order.

Comment: and I've just spent a long time discovering that space characters may or may not be ignored, and that this changed depending on whether I was running tests locally, or doing `R CMD check`

Comment: A better method is to use `stringr::str_sort` and you can assign locale so it will have consistent result.

Comment: Only if you are willing or required to accept the heavier burden of `stringr` dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting depends on locale.
My solution for that is the following...

I create `~/.Renviron` file

```
cat ~/.Renviron 
#LC_ALL=C
```

then in R sorting is in C locale

```r
x=c("A", "B", "d", "F", "g", "H")
sort(x)
#[1] "A" "B" "F" "H" "d" "g"
```