# Case insensitive sort of vector of string in R

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
 mylist <- c("MBT.LN.ID", "ISA51VG.LN.ID", "R848.LN.ID", "sHz.LN.ID", "FK565.LN.ID",
    "bCD.LN.ID", "MALP2s.LN.ID", "ADX.LN.ID", "AddaVax.LN.ID", "FCA.LN.ID",
    "Pam3CSK4.LN.ID", "D35.LN.ID", "ALM.LN.ID", "K3.LN.ID", "K3SPG.LN.ID",
    "MPLA.LN.ID", "DMXAA.LN.ID", "cGAMP.LN.ID", "Poly_IC.LN.ID",
    "cdiGMP.LN.ID")
```

I'd like to sort them alphabetically in case-insensitive manner.

The expected output is this:

```
 [1] "AddaVax.LN.ID"  "ADX.LN.ID"      "ALM.LN.ID"      "bCD.LN.ID"      "cdiGMP.LN.ID"   "cGAMP.LN.ID"   
 [7] "D35.LN.ID"      "DMXAA.LN.ID"    "FCA.LN.ID"      "FK565.LN.ID"    "ISA51VG.LN.ID"  "K3.LN.ID"      
[13] "K3SPG.LN.ID"    "MALP2s.LN.ID"   "MBT.LN.ID"      "MPLA.LN.ID"     "Pam3CSK4.LN.ID" "Poly_IC.LN.ID" 
[19] "R848.LN.ID"     "sHz.LN.ID"
```

I tried this but failed (Using R.3.2.0 alpha):

```
> sort(mylist)
 [1] "ADX.LN.ID"      "ALM.LN.ID"      "AddaVax.LN.ID"  "D35.LN.ID"
 [5] "DMXAA.LN.ID"    "FCA.LN.ID"      "FK565.LN.ID"    "ISA51VG.LN.ID"
 [9] "K3.LN.ID"       "K3SPG.LN.ID"    "MALP2s.LN.ID"   "MBT.LN.ID"
[13] "MPLA.LN.ID"     "Pam3CSK4.LN.ID" "Poly_IC.LN.ID"  "R848.LN.ID"
[17] "bCD.LN.ID"      "cGAMP.LN.ID"    "cdiGMP.LN.ID"   "sHz.LN.ID"
```

Comment: The output of `sort` depends on your locale: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229428/3710546

Comment: I get the expected output with `sort(mylist)`. What is your locale ?

Comment: @CathG:`LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C`

Comment: well maybe that's where it comes from, see the link provided by Pascal. Does the same thing happen with `order`? (`mylist[order(mylist)]`)

Comment: @Pascal While I do agree that this is local specific, I don't think that OP needs to reset their local each time they want to conduct a `sort`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Did I even suggest this?

Comment: @Pascal no you didn't. You provided a link and I thought you were suggesting it as a possible solution.

Comment: @DavidArenburg It was more to add some context, because some sorting issues were directly related to the locale. I agree that switching locale might be painful.

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
mylist[order(tolower(mylist))]
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg, yes, I didn't want to change my local settings but I was wondering if it would work (thank you for doing it). So Collate=C makes order and sort case sensitive

Answer (score 6):

As noted by @Pascal, this is documented in `help(Comparison)` and `sort` is local specific. One Option is switching your local (for example `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "us")`), but that could be inconvenient. Another option could be using `gtools::mixedsort` which could be also useful because you string also contains numbers.

```
library(gtools)
mixedsort(mylist)

# [1] "AddaVax.LN.ID"  "ADX.LN.ID"      "ALM.LN.ID"      "bCD.LN.ID"      "cdiGMP.LN.ID"   "cGAMP.LN.ID"    "D35.LN.ID"      "DMXAA.LN.ID"    "FCA.LN.ID"      "FK565.LN.ID"   
# [11] "ISA51VG.LN.ID"  "K3.LN.ID"       "K3SPG.LN.ID"    "MALP2s.LN.ID"   "MBT.LN.ID"      "MPLA.LN.ID"     "Pam3CSK4.LN.ID" "Poly_IC.LN.ID"  "R848.LN.ID"     "sHz.LN.ID"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
> library(searchable)
> sort(ignore.case(mylist))
 [1] "AddaVax.LN.ID"  "ADX.LN.ID"      "ALM.LN.ID"      "bCD.LN.ID"      "cdiGMP.LN.ID"  
 [6] "cGAMP.LN.ID"    "D35.LN.ID"      "DMXAA.LN.ID"    "FCA.LN.ID"      "FK565.LN.ID"   
[11] "ISA51VG.LN.ID"  "K3.LN.ID"       "K3SPG.LN.ID"    "MALP2s.LN.ID"   "MBT.LN.ID"     
[16] "MPLA.LN.ID"     "Pam3CSK4.LN.ID" "Poly_IC.LN.ID"  "R848.LN.ID"     "sHz.LN.ID"
```