# R - Can you compare which value is first in alphabetical order?

Tags: r, alphabetical

If I have the values:

```
x <- 'random'
y <- 'word'
```

Can I do a test to see if x alphabetically comes before or after y? In this example something similar to a function that would produce:

> alphabetical(x,y) -> True
>
> alphabetical(y,x) -> False

Comment: `x < y` and `y < x`

Comment: Related: [What are the R sorting rules of character vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229408/what-are-the-r-sorting-rules).

Comment: `alphabetical <- function(...) !is.unsorted(c(...)); alphabetical(x, y); alphabetical(y, x)` works for any number of strings

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The built-in comparison operators work fine on strings.

```
x < y
[1] TRUE
y < x
[1] FALSE
```

Note the details in the help page `?Comparison`, or perhaps more intuitively,  `` ?`<` ``, especially the importances of locale:

> Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the strings using the collating sequence *of the locale in use* [...]
>
> Beware of making *any* assumptions about the collation order

Comment: Just wanted you to get the credit since you had it in the comments 8 minutes prior to the accepted answer.

Comment: @RichScriven Appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
alphabetical <- function(x,y){x < y}
```