# What's happening behind the conversion of factor to numeric?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Here is a small `data.frame`:

```
e = data.frame(A=c(letters[1:5], 1:5))
```

I am a little bit confused regarding what's happening when I execute the following command:

```
unclass(e$A) %>% as.numeric()
```

I am getting the following output:

```
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5
```

why `a:e` is treated as `6:10`?

Comment: I'd say it is because 1:5 was already used within the data and the function tries to resolve without causing ambiguity. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question raises a problem that is burried deep in the heart of every computer language. It's the question of how to order characters.

The R help file `?sort` says this:

> The sort order for character vectors will depend on the collating
>   sequence of the locale in use: see Comparison. The sort order for
>   factors is the order of their levels

So you can try to find your locale. You also want to check the [ISO 14651](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_ordering_rules) standard that defines international string ordering and comparison rules. 
Depending on your location, you might find out differences of ordering very specitic characters but regarding numbers, i guess they are always first.

```
"a">"1"
#### [1] TRUE
"a">"A"
#### [1] FALSE
```

**Edit:**
About the alphabetical precedence between upper case and lower case, it will indeed depend on your system locale (English follow `us_en` and non-English locales can follow `ASCII` or other see this [wikipedia paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_order)). Try this:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")
sort(c(1,2,3,"a", "b", "c", "A", "B", "C"))
#### [1] "1" "2" "3" "A" "B" "C" "a" "b" "c"
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "French_France.1252")
sort(c(1,2,3,"a", "b", "c", "A", "B", "C"))
#### [1] "1" "2" "3" "a" "A" "b" "B" "c" "C"
```

Similar issues have actually been discussed in this other [So question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229408/3871924)

Comment: hi ,could you check the code e1=data.frame(A=c(1:3,letters[1:3],LETTERS[1:3])) ;unclass(e1$A) %>% as.numeric().after the output getting 1 2 3 4 6 8 5 7 9.so as of understanding numbers are comes first.after alphabetics,but again observe that small letters are comes first after capital letters.But it is against the "a">"A".

Comment: as of my understanding unicode characters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters.

Comment: which unicode system R follows? sorry of my grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 8):

`data.frame` makes a factor, this can be seen by using `str(e)`:

> ```
> 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  1 variable:
>  $ A: Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5
> ```

This factor has different levels, ordered alphabetically (where R sorts numbers before letters), `levels(e$A)`:

> ```
>  [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
> ```

`as.numeric` converts a factor to the indices of the levels, i.e. the first level gets value 1 (which means 1 remains 1) and the sixth level gets value 6 (which means `"a"` becomes 6).

In this case you actually already force this conversion with `unclass()`, which results in the numeric vector you see. The `as.numeric` then only also drops the `levels` attribute.

`?Comparison` tells us any comparison between character vectors (such as `sort`ing them) are based on the collating sequence of the current locale.

Note: this is independent of the `%>%`.

Comment: why so are the numeric sorted before the letters? (i guess that's the main reason of the OP's question)

Comment: hi thank for response, then what about this ?     e1=data.frame(A=c(1:5,letters[1:5]))    and resulting output is 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

Comment: @ agenis .yes,that's my intention to find why numeric precedence.if you find out any. could you update the comment thank you.

Comment: @user7462639, that case is the same, levels are always reordered alphabetically, and numbers come first.