# Different R base::sort result in different platform

Tags: r

This is a simple but weird problem. I'm using `sort` on a character vector.

```
Browse[1]> x
[1] "OU anisotropic"  "OUF anisotropic" "OU isotropic"    "OUF isotropic"  
Browse[1]> sort(x)
[1] "OU anisotropic"  "OU isotropic"    "OUF anisotropic" "OUF isotropic"  
Browse[1]> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Very simple, however I found sort didn't give expected result in linux, R 3.4.1. Note y is different from x above, but the sort result is not right anyway.

```
> y
[1] "OU anisotropic"  "OUF anisotropic" "OUF isotropic"   "OU isotropic"   
> sort(y)
[1] "OU anisotropic"  "OUF anisotropic" "OUF isotropic"   "OU isotropic"   
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 18.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

I guess it's locale related? How can I control the sort function to have consistent result?

I tried `stringr::str_sort` which seem to have consistent result, probably because there is a `local = "en"` parameter.

But I think there should be some way with base sort too. The data is simple character vector so there should not be any special sort function involved.

Comment: did you try setting a method argument

Comment: sort is a function of your locale

Comment: Thanks for the link, it seemed to be locale related, and base::sort ignored space in some locale. That's what confused me: I thought even with different locale the example should sort same, but I didn't realize space could be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Henrik for the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229408/what-are-the-r-sorting-rules-of-character-vectors). I guessed it's locale related and searched but didn't find that post.

`help(Comparison)` have more detailed information. What confused me is that I thought my example should sort same in even different locale, however `base::sort` may ignored spaces in some locale.

I found `stringr::str_sort` have a `locale = "en"` parameter, so you can have consistent result across platforms.