# How does R determine the default level ordering of a factor variable when importing data?

Tags: r

Simple question, but when I import data and R automatically detects that some of the columns are "factor" variables, how does it figure out the default ordering of the factor variable?  It doesn't appear random, since often the order just happens to be correct, even for factors with quite a bit of levels.

Comment: See `?factor`: "**Arguments** `levels`: [...] The default is the unique set of values taken by `as.character(x)`, sorted into increasing order of `x`. **Warning**: The levels of a factor are by default sorted, but the sort order may well depend on the locale at the time of creation, and should not be assumed to be ASCII". Then check [What are the R sorting rules of character vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229408/what-are-the-r-sorting-rules-of-character-vectors) which basically points to `?sort`, **Details**, and `?Comparison`.

Comment: Side note regarding "_when I import data and R automatically detects that some of the columns are "factor" variables_", it suggests that you don't have the current R version; from `4.0.0` R "uses a `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` default, and hence by default no longer converts strings to factors in calls to `data.frame()` and `read.table()`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default ordering is alphabetic

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- factor(sample(letters[1:10], 50, replace = TRUE))
levels(v1)
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Explains why the numeric factors "happened to be correct", because alphabetizing numbers just means putting it in numeric order.

Comment: except that lexicographic/alphabetic ordering might not do what you want for mixtures of numbers with different numbers of digits ...

Answer (score 2):

The sorting is lexicographic. We can see how R would arrange all Ascii characters as factors like this:

```r
levels(as.factor(sample(strsplit(rawToChar(as.raw(32:126)), "")[[1]])))
#>  [1] "'"  "-"  " "  "!"  "\"" "#"  "$"  "%"  "&"  "("  ")"  "*"  ","  "." 
#> [15] "/"  ":"  ";"  "?"  "@"  "["  "\\" "]"  "^"  "_"  "`"  "{"  "|"  "}" 
#> [29] "~"  "+"  "<"  "="  ">"  "0"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8" 
#> [43] "9"  "a"  "A"  "b"  "B"  "c"  "C"  "d"  "D"  "e"  "E"  "f"  "F"  "g" 
#> [57] "G"  "h"  "H"  "i"  "I"  "j"  "J"  "k"  "K"  "l"  "L"  "m"  "M"  "n" 
#> [71] "N"  "o"  "O"  "p"  "P"  "q"  "Q"  "r"  "R"  "s"  "S"  "t"  "T"  "u" 
#> [85] "U"  "v"  "V"  "w"  "W"  "x"  "X"  "y"  "Y"  "z"  "Z"
```

Comment: ...but see **Warning** in `?factor` (my comment above).

Comment: Very good point @Henrik This is one of the major ways in which locale can cause different outputs (even when we are not dealing with times)