# How sort function works for vector in R?

Tags: r

Hi I am new to R programming and I came across the function sort(). I have defined a vector as

`v10 <- c('ram',12,'ann',TRUE)`

and I am aware of the fact that vectors are created using homogeneous data otherwise implicit coercion happens.The type of the vector is ***Character***. And when I apply `sort(v10)` it gives me the output as

`"12"   "ann"  "ram"  "TRUE"`.

So my query is how is sorting happening here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the relevant help page is `?Comparison`. String comparisons are done using your current "locale" since different languages sort characters in a different order sometimes. The rule for your locale seems to be numbers, then lowercase letters followed by uppercase (0,1,2,...,a,A,b,B,c,C, etc...)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229408/what-are-the-r-sorting-rules-of-character-vectors might help you