# How string comparison works in R?

Tags: r, string, comparison

probably very silly question. I can't understand how R is handling character and string comparison:

```
"a" < "A"
TRUE
charToRaw("a")
61
charToRaw("A")
41
```

Someone knows what is going on here!?

I tried:

```
"tom" > "richard"
TRUE
```

and I was guessing R is comparing "t" is greater than "r" so the following was making sense to me:

```
charToRaw("t")
74
charToRaw("r")
72
```

But then I tried this:

```
"a" < "A"
charToRaw("a")
charToRaw("A")
TRUE
61
41
```

... and got lost!

Comment: Probably duplicating: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229408/what-are-the-r-sorting-rules-of-character-vectors

Comment: R doesn't use the raw character code points (or ASCII values). R uses a locale-aware sort that is well behaved for the language specified in your locale. `charToRaw` will not give you information about how values will be sorted, it will just tell you what byte is being used to represent the character.