# Sorting character string with white-space - Incorrect results in Ubuntu version of R

Tags: r, sorting, whitespace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the R sorting rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229408/what-are-the-r-sorting-rules)

We are trying to sort gene location coordinates in my data matrix. Format for the column is:

> xx xxxxxx

Where xx is chromosome number from 1 to 23, and xxxxxx is numeric string for location of the gene.

In particular, I am interested in doing ascending sorting of data matrix first by chromosome number and then by location of genes, e.g., Gene 1 on chromosome 5, location 21 comes at the top of Gene 2 on chromosome 17, location 34.

In R (2.15.0 x64) on Windows, I see following results:

```
> '5 21' < '12 14'
[1] FALSE
> ' 5 21' < '12 14' # white space prefixed to first digit corrects sort order.
[1] TRUE
```

In R (2.15.1 x64) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I see following results:

```
> '5 21' < '12 14'
[1] FALSE
> ' 5 21' < '12 14' # white space does not correct sort order.
[1] FALSE
```

This is weird to me as Windows version corrects sort order by ignoring white space and then considering numeric sorting (05 vs 11) while Linux version sorts character by character (5 vs 1). Windows version assumes prefixed white space as 0 (I guess) and then considers two digits for comparison but Linux version ignores white space and compare second digit of first string to first digit of second string.

I have found mixedsort {gtools} function in R to overcome this issue but thought this is worth reporting and get help on fixing this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Character sorting is locale-specific.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, that is what I needed. I used `Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C") ` and linux version is now showing correct sorting. [Additional info is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4245365/1243763)