# Make mixedsort case sensitive? [r]

Tags: r, sorting

I'm trying to sort a character vector in a natural order (as a human would sort it) but considering case differences. For example, in the vector below I would like to sort all the small "m" and the big "M" independently.

```
x<- c("m10", "M10", "m11", "m12", "m2", "M2", "m3", "M3", "m4", "M4", "yo1", "yo2")
```

so that it looks like:

```
  DesiredSort(x)

 [1] "M2" "M3" "M4" "M10" "m2" "m3" "m4" "m10" "m11" "m12" "yo1" "yo2"
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245196/do-not-ignore-case-in-sorting-character-strings) I got how to make `sort` take case into account:

```
sortC <- function(...) {
  a <- Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")
  on.exit(Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", a))
  Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")
  sort(...)
} 
sortC(x)

[1] "M10" "M2"  "M3"  "M4"  "m10" "m11" "m12" "m2"  "m3"  "m4" "yo1" "yo2"
```

But that does not give the natural order. I know `mixedsort` from gtools will properly put m2 before m10, so that:

```
mixedsort(x)

[1] "m2"  "M2"  "m3"  "M3"  "m4"  "M4"  "m10" "M10" "m11" "m12" "yo1" "yo2"
```

But `mixedsort` specifically ignores case of character string, so doing a similar function to SortC does not work.

I have several vectors to sort in this way, and they include characters not included in the example, so it would be great to find a general way of doing this.

Ideas? Maybe there is something obvious I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: In your expected output, should "m11" and "m10" be the other way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How general do you need the solution to be?  This custom solution below fits your dataset, but it isn't entirely clear (at least to me) what you want to happen in the general case of a vector containing arbitrary strings.

```
DesiredSort <- function(x)
{
  library(stringr)

  locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")
  on.exit(Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", locale))
  Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")

  x_matches <- str_match(x, "(^[[:alpha:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)")[, 2:3]

  x_data <- data.frame(
    letter = x_matches[, 1], 
    number = as.numeric(x_matches[, 2])
  )
  o <- with(x_data, order(letter, number))
  x[o]
}

x <- c("m10", "M10", "m11", "m12", "m2", "M2", "m3", "M3", "m4", "M4", "yo1", "yo2")
expected <- c("M2", "M3", "M4", "M10", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m10", "m11", "m12", "yo1", "yo2")
stopifnot(identical(DesiredSort(x), expected))
```

Comment: Thanks @Richie, I should have said that I have several vectors to order in a similar way but that they have different characters. For example you could add "yo1", "yo2", to that vector. So I think I need something more general? I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: @A.Mstt: Updated with more general solution.  Consider writing some test cases to fully understand the form of your inputs and what you think the output should be.  Take a look at the `testthat` or `RUnit` packages for this.